# Linking trouble in xcode 4

Tags: xcode, linker, objective-c++

I'm new to the world of iOS programming and MacOS at all, and this question is built terribly, but still. I'm learning all this for a month. Till now i didn't have to ask questions anywhere because I could find answers using google.
But now I'm trying to migrate from usual Obj-C to Obj-C++. My teacher gave me some library to include and it had **#include "libkern/OSAtomic.h"**. First build failed and wrote that there was no OSAtomic found. I figured that I needed to include Kernel.framework to my project.
But when I did that there was another error, something like it couldn't find kernel or something.
Sorry for this spontaneous question, I'm not at my mac right now, but if someone had something like that - he could answer question and help me right away. Else - i'll post exact error when I'll be at my mac.

Error is:
ld: framework not found Kernel
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1

UPD
Problem solved. This include (which was in angle brackets already, btw), was included after all. Kernel framework was not only unnecessary, but harmful - it supposedly made app build for MacOS instead of iOS.
I removed Kernel.framework and found which methods linker had problem with and with a few google magic it was found out that Security.framework was needed. Program builded successfully after that.

Thank you everybody for your responses.

Comment: Please post the exact error, and if you can, the command line which generated it. The most obvious thing from what you've posted would be to use `#include <libkern/OSAtomic.h>` since the header is within a framework and not in your source code. The angle brackets indicate that it's a framework header, whereas using double quotes indicates that it's a source file in your source code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will definitely try this. If nothing helps - I'll post all required info. Unfortunately, I'll be able to do it only at Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want the Kernel.framework, as that's used only for kernel extension development - so remove that dependency again. Instead, I suspect you need to install XCode's command-line/UNIX stuff, which will install a file /usr/include/libkern/OSAtomic.h which the compiler should be able to find without any framework references. You can download extra packages via XCode -> Preferences... (⌘,) -> Downloads.

Comment: You were right, Kernel had absolutely nothing to do with my error. Sorry it took so long to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this also, that is different.

You can just include it with

```
#import <libkern/OSAtomic.h>
```

This is with Xcode 5.0.2